# R lpsolve binary find all possible solutions

Tags: r, optimization, binary, linear-programming, lpsolve

I have a linear programming problem. All variables are binary and I want to get all possible solutions.I know that I can set parameter num.bin.solns to provide multiple solutions. But is there any easy way to ask for all possible solutions?

For example in below case I know that the maximum number of answers is 6. But if I don't know the maximum possible solutions then how can I set the num.bin.solns parameter such that it would return all possible solutions?

```
library("lpSolve")
A=matrix (c(1,1,1,1), nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)
b=(2)
signs='=='
c_=rep(0,4)
res = lpSolve::lp('max', c_, A, signs, b,  all.bin = TRUE, num.bin.solns=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. `lpSove` actually gives you the **num.bin.solns** that it finds, and you can access that using the $ notation.

You can initially set the num.bin.solns to be some large number (say 1000). And then access the **mylp$num.bin.solns** to get the exact value.

```
mylp <- lp('max', c_, A, signs, b,  all.bin = TRUE, num.bin.solns=1000)
numcols <- 4
numsols <- mylp$num.bin.solns

solutions <- matrix(head(mylp$solution, numcols*numsols), nrow=numsols, byrow=TRUE)

> numsols
[1] 6
```

And you can print out the individual solutions:

```
> solutions
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    1    0
[5,]    1    1    0    0
[6,]    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: thanks, let me try it. QQ: any idea what mylp$solution has 1 element more than what we expect? i.e. if we put num.bin.solns=1000 then the length of solution vector is 4001...it should be 4000...what does 4001th element indicate?

Comment: Good question. I tried searching for it, but not sure where that -1 comes from. The documentation didn't help me. Hence you see me doing the head( ) to cut that out.

Comment: I tried your answer and it makes sense. The only problem is that if a problem is huge then it slows the processing down and sometimes returns an error. Instead of specifying num.bin.solns=1000, is there a way to say that return all the possible solutions?

Comment: If the problem is large, there will be an exponential number of solutions, hence the slowness. At this point, there seems to be no easy alternative to setting num.bin.solns to be a large number and then interrogating mylp$solution.

Comment: ok. Thanks. Please let me know if you come across any other alternative in future..