# R - Combinations of a dataframe with constraints

Tags: r

I'm trying to make an R script for fantasy football (proper UK football, not hand egg :-)) where I can input a list of players in a csv and it will spit out every 11-player combination, which meet various constraints.

Here's my sample dataframe:

```
df <- read.csv("Filename.csv",
               header = TRUE)
    > print(df)
                       Name Positon Team   Salary
    1             Eric Dier       D  TOT  9300000
    2          Erik Pieters       D  STO  9200000
    3       Christian Fuchs       D  LEI  9100000
    4       Héctor Bellerín       D  ARS  9000000
    5       Charlie Daniels       D  BOU  9000000
    6            Ben Davies       D  TOT  8900000
    7    Federico Fernández       D  SWA  8800000
    8       Per Mertesacker       D  ARS  8800000
    9        Alberto Moreno       D  LIV  8700000
    10       Chris Smalling       D  MUN  8700000
    11       Seamus Coleman       D  EVE  8700000
    12       Jan Vertonghen       D  TOT  8700000
    13        Romelu Lukaku       F  EVE 12700000
    14           Harry Kane       F  TOT 12500000
    15           Max Gradel       F  BOU 11900000
    16       Alexis Sánchez       F  ARS 11300000
    17          Jamie Vardy       F  LEI 11200000
    18         Theo Walcott       F  ARS 10700000
    19       Olivier Giroud       F  ARS 10700000
    20        Wilfried Bony       F  MCI 10000000
    21 Kristoffer Nordfeldt       G  SWA  7000000
    22             Joe Hart       G  MCI  6800000
    23            Jack Rose       G  WBA  6600000
    24        Asmir Begovic       G  CHE  6600000
    25           Mesut Özil       M  ARS 15600000
    26         Riyad Mahrez       M  LEI 15200000
    27         Ross Barkley       M  EVE 13300000
    28        Dimitri Payet       M  WHM 12800000
    29              Willian       M  CHE 12500000
    30      Bertrand Traore       M  CHE 12500000
    31      Kevin De Bruyne       M  MCI 12400000
```

And the constraints are as follows:

1) The total salary of each 11-player lineup cannot exceed 100,000,000

2) There can only be a maximum of four players from one team. E.g. four player from 'CHE' (Chelsea).

3) There is a limit of how many players within each 11-player lineup can be from each position. There can be:

1 G (goalkeeper), 3 to 4 D (defender), 3 to 5 M (midfielder), 1 to 3 F (forward)

I'd like every 11 player combination that meets the above contraints to be returned. Order is not important (e.g. 1,2,3 is considered the same as 2,1,3 and shouldn't be duplicated) and a player can appear in more than one lineup.

I've done a fair bit of research and played around but can't seem to get anywhere with this. I'm new to R. I don't expect anyone to nail this for me, but if someone could point a newbie like myself in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try for each constraint ? where is the code ?

Comment: I don't know how many players you have in your csv file but hopefully you realize that choosing __all possible__ sets of 11 out of 31 things, disregarding order, gets you 84,672,315 combinations to test. There is no easy way out here. You have to build the algorithm that constructs your teams according to your specification and I don't think that any library would be of particular help here.

Comment: @kliron: the problem described by the author is a classical Constraint Satisfaction Problem. These problems are common in AI. The first part of your  answer assumes that the problem is solved using butte force techniques. The second part point into the right direction. In fact, these can be solved using any CSP solver, which do some kind of clever solution construction. Luckily there are plenty algorithms and libraries.  First: search based ones, which I wouldn't implement/expect in R. Second algorithms which turn the problem into an optimisation problem, basically a set of linear equations.

Comment: See my comment below. Thanks for the LPSolve hint, I didn't know about that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute-force way to tackle this, (which is also beautifully parallelizable and guarantees you **all** possible combinations) is to calculate all 11-player permutations and then filter out the combinations that don't conform to your limits in a stepwise manner.

To make a program like this fit into your computer's memory, give each player a unique integer ID and create vectors of IDs as team sets. When you then implement your filters your functions can refer to the player info by that ID in a single dataframe.

Say `df` is your data frame with all player data.

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Get all combinations of ids:

```
# This will take a long time or run out of memory!
# In my 2.8Gz laptop took 466 seconds just for your 31 players
teams <- combn(df$id, 11)
```

Of course, if your dataframe is big (like hundreds of players) this implementation could take impossibly long to finish. You probably would be better off just sampling 11-sets from your player set without replacement and construct teams in an "on demand" fashion.

A more clever way is to partition your dataset according to player position into - one for goalkeepers, one for defence, etc. And then use the above approach to create permutations of different players from each position and combine the end results. It would take ridiculously less amount of time, it would still be parallelizable and exhaustive (give you all possible combinations).

Comment: The problem described by the author is a classical Constraint Satiscfaction Problem. In a single class of problem, there is typically a phase transition, dividing the instances of one class in three groups. The ones which are trivial to find a solution, the ones which don't have a solution and the ones which are NP hard to solve (the ones in the phase transition).
Your solution will most likely only find solutions in the trivial to solve instances.
There are sampling based algorithms dedicated to CSP. But I would suggest to use R as implementation language for any of these algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the the response. I like this method; mainly because a programming newbie like me can understand exactly what the code is doing. I guess the next step would be the use a for loop to filter the raw combinations through the constraints.

Comment: @CAFEBABE If you are refering to the combinatorial search approach I already stated the limitations and hinted to the way heuristics can change an unsolvable problem to a solvable one. My intention was not to give a formal, general solution but to point to interesting directions for OP to solve this.

Comment: The problem is not the combinatorial explotation per se. There are many problems with a combinatorial explosion, which are easy to solve.
Your ideas work under the assumption that many assignments are a solution.
However, the problem with sampling is obvious when you try to solve the problem of the OP.
The problem with partitioning is that you can only partition along one variable. However there are 2 complex constraints (team+price)require more elaborate techniques.
A bit theoretical foundation: Most likely finding a single player assignment is already NP. Hence, the problem class is #P... ;)

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved as linear integer program using the library LPSolve.
This kind of problems are very well solvable -- opposed to what has been written before -- as typical the number of solutions are much smaller than the domain size.

You can add for each Player a zero one variable, whether or not that player is in the team.

The package can be installed using

```
 install.packages("lpSolve")
 install.packages("lpSolveAPI")
```

The documentation can be found at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/lpSolve.pdf

First constraint sum of players 11

The salary is basically a sum of all players variable multiplied by the salary column and so on....

To get a proper solutions you need to specify in

```
lp.solve(all.bin=TRUE
```

Such that all variables referring to players are either zero or one.

( I understood that you are trying to learn, that's why I refrain from giving a full solution)

**EDIT**
As I got down-voted probably because of not giving the full solution. Kind of sad as as the original author explicitly wrote that he doesn't expect a full solution

```
library(lpSolve)

df <- read.csv("/tmp/football.csv",header = TRUE,sep=";")

f.obj <- rep(1,nrow(df))

f.con <- 
  matrix(c(f.obj <- rep(1,nrow(df)),
    as.vector(df$Salary),
    (df$Positon=="G") *1.0,
    (df$Positon=="D") *1.0,
    (df$Positon=="D") *1.0,
    (df$Positon=="M") *1.0,
    (df$Positon=="M") *1.0,
    (df$Positon=="F") *1.0,
    (df$Positon=="F") *1.0),nrow=9,byrow= TRUE)

f.dir <- c("==", "<=","==",">=","<=",">=","<=",">=","<=")

f.rhs<- c(11, #number players
       100000000, #salary
       1 , #Goalkeeper
       3 , # def min
       4 , # def max
       3 , # mdef min
       5,  # mdef max
       1,  # for, min
       3  # wor, max
       )



solutions <-   lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs,all.bin=TRUE)
```

I didn't add the Team Constraint as it wouldn't have provided any additionally insights here....

** EDIT2 **
This might come handy if you change your data set
[R lpsolve binary find all possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666795/r-lpsolve-binary-find-all-possible-solutions)

Comment: As this answer now stands, it is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Jaap: the questions author explicitly wrote: I don't expect anyone to nail this for me, 
Hence I only gave directions.

Comment: Much better now! (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the response buddy. I have zero experience using LPSolve so would probably have to do some reading.