# Possible combinations of ranked components

Tags: r, logic

I would like to find number of possible combinations for this questions. This question is exactly a simplified version of a real time scenario where people choose a station where they want to work and provide their preferential(ranked) list. Please help me to take a stab at this question. I would like to use R to solve this problem.

[image]

```
j<-c("Y", "X", "Z", "W")
l<-c("X", "Z", "W", "Y")
p<-c("Y", "Z", "X", "W")
t<-c("X", "Y", "Z", "W")
```

I want to find all the possible vector/s that meets the restrictions mentioned.

Wanted to add images to show the actual questions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks homework to me...

Comment: Kind of, it's a reasoning / logical question in a LSAT book. I just wanted to know how, if I needed to solve it using a program, to do it in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 1):

(*warning: brute force answer*)
Given that the space to explore is rather small (basically `n!/(n-k)!` elements if `k` employees choose from `n` cities, so here 4! = 24 elements), you could write something like:

```
require(combinat)
condition1 <- function(combination,...) {}  # returns TRUE if condition1 is met
# ...
condition3 <- function(combination,...) {}  # returns TRUE if condition3 is met
space <- combinat::permn(c("W","X","Y","Z"))      # a list of all permutations
lapply(space, 
       function(x) if (condition1(x) && condition2(x) && condition3(x)) {return(x)})
```

Of course it's not super elegant, but it allows you to manually code in potentially "exotic" conditions and let R do the mundane work in `lapply`.

With a large number of conditions, I would group them in a list of functions `conditions` and replace the last line with `function(x) if all(lapply(conditions, function(c) do.call(c,x))) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

(It looks as homework to me that is why I don't want to give away to much details)
You can use lpSolve for this kind of problems.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/lpSolve.pdf

The basic idea is that you define a linear equation. For each person/station combination you introduce a variable, e.g. `jx` person `j` is at station `x`.

Then you can define the constraints, e.g.

```
#each person one station
jx+jy+jz+jw=1
#each station one person
jx+ly+... =1
```

Based on your objective you can then define the objective function.
This kind of equations can then be fed into lpsolve

I recently described the usage on another example
[R - Combinations of a dataframe with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480151/r-combinations-of-a-dataframe-with-constraints/34480260#34480260)