# lp_solve all optimal solutions

Tags: lpsolve, integer-programming

I am using the [lp_solve java wrapper](http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/Java/README.html) to find an optimal solution to an IP. Is there an easy way to find all solutions? Or do I have to add new constraints to rule out the current solution and re-solve?

Comment: In many cases there are an infinite number of optimal solutions (e.g. `max 0*x s.t. x integer`).

Comment: yes I was hoping that, given a model with only binary variables, it would be able to find all optimal solutions (some of the other solvers do). guess not?

Comment: At least the R interface as num.bin.solns for that (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28666795/3093387), but I'm struggling to see how that maps to the java interface. Looking at the lpSolve package C source code, it's just repeatedly adding a constraint to cut off the optimal solution `(1 for all the variables set to 1, -1 for all the variables set to 0)'x <= numSet-1` and then re-solving.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. i guess I'll have to do that myself.