# Many optimal solution using lpSolve in R

Tags: r, lpsolve

I am running a lp optimization using lpSolve package. The $solution value show me only one result, but I know there are more than one optimal solution. How can I collect the others solutions?

Comment: might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666795/r-lpsolve-binary-find-all-possible-solutions

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, unfortunately, the results aren't binary. They are integer.

Comment: Use all.bin=TRUE

Comment: You can add a cut to forbid the current integer solution and resolve. However, the general integer cut is not that simple. Many modern solvers have something called a **solution pool**. They can give a set of alternative optimal integer solutions. LpSolve does not have this facility.